# Call function on resize and on load using an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a directive to call a function in my controller when a div get resized:

**VIEW**

```
<div id="tables-container" data-tap-disabled="true" on-size-changed="changeSize"></div>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('onSizeChanged', ['$window', '$timeout', function ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            onSizeChanged: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, $element, attr) {
            var element = $element[0];

            cacheElementSize(scope, element);
            $window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

            function cacheElementSize(scope, element) {
                scope.cachedElementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
                scope.cachedElementHeight = element.offsetHeight;
            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                var isSizeChanged = scope.cachedElementWidth != element.offsetWidth || scope.cachedElementHeight != element.offsetHeight;
                if (isSizeChanged) {
                    var expression = scope.onSizeChanged();
                    $timeout(function () {
                        expression(element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight);
                    }, 500);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.changeSize = function(w, h) {
    //DO SOMETHING WITH w AND h...
};
```

This works great onResize. The thing that is puzzling me is **how can I lunch the on-size-changed function when the page is loaded (onReady)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive and attach it on your top most element where you attach ng-app directive,In that directive's link function you can dispatch event which will be listened by all the handler's applied by your directive.

```
app.directive('ngReady', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function() {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));    
    }
  }
});
```

or you can modify your directive and add this below code

```
$element.ready(function(){
    scope.$apply(function(){
      onWindowResize();
    })
})
```

I created a working demo [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzeX3TGttY8sylfA2HPt?p=preview)
Hope it will help :)